# Create a json object with array of arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm using `array_add($array, 'key', 'value');` to create the data structure.

```
foreach ($archives as $archive){
    $results = array_add($results, $archive->year, 
              array($archive->month => array('name' => $archive->month_name)));
}
```

If i `json_encode()`the `$results` i get this output:

```
{ 
   2015: {
       02: {name:'February'}
   }
}
```

But i want something like:

```
{
   2015: {
       02: {name:'February'},
       01: {name:'January'}
   }
}
```

And of course this should works for different years too.

Comment: `array_add` isn't a core php function, can you show the function aswell? Besides `$results` is overwritten in every iteration.

Comment: Why are you using a (IMHO pointless, and messy-looking) function (`array_add`), when you could just write `$results[$archive->year] = array($archive->month => array('name' => $archive->month_name));`? Oh, and could it be that _"January"_ isn't int `$results` because it's not in the `$archives` to begin with? check those values, too

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem with your code i get the same output but with January and not February.

Comment: @idknow: Because you'd need to check if `$results[$archive->year]` doesn't already exist, if it does, your code currently reassigns it (overwriting the array that it already holds), I'll post an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In response to my comments - here's what I'd do:

```
foreach ($archives as $archive)
{
    if (!isset($results[$archive->year]))
    {//if the year-key doesn't exist yet, create it
     //if it already exists, this part will be skipped
        $results[$archive->year] = array();
    }
    //then add the values
    $results[$archive->year][$archive->month] = array(
        'name' => $archive->month_name
    );
}
```

That's all there is to it, no need for a home-made function or anything like that

Answer (score 0):

How about 
array_push($array, 'key', 'value');

Comment: That won't work at all, that'll push `'key'` and `'value'` as separate values onto `$array` consecutively [see the manual](http://www.php.net/array_push)